# Express.js : POST data as KEY of a req.body object instead of VALUE of req.body?

Tags: json, node.js, post, express

from the client I'm doing :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/create',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            theme: "somevalue",
            snippet: {
                name: "somename",
                content: "somevalue"
            }
        }), 
        complete: function (response)
        {

        }
    });
```

on the server ( `node.js/express.js` ) I'm doing :

```
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
.......
... 
app.post('/create', function (req, res)
{
   var dataReceived = req.body;
});
```

I expected the value of  `dataReceived` to be :

```
{
   "theme" : "somevalue",
   "snippet" : {
     "name": "somename",
     "content" : "somevalue"
   } 
}
```

Instead the value of `dataReceived` was :

```
{ 
 '{"theme":"somevalue","snippet":"name":"somename","content":"somevalue"}}': '' 
}
```

This is really weird and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

from the [BodyParser module documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) :

> bodyParser.urlencoded(options)
>
> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies. This parser
>   accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic
>   inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
>
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the
>   request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This object will
>   contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array
>   (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).

Is this related to my problem ?

Comment: you dont need to JSON.stringify the request on the frontend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove Stringify in your client side

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/create',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            theme: "somevalue",
            snippet: {
                name: "somename",
                content: "somevalue"
            }
        }, 
        complete: function (response)
        {

        }
    });
```

or parse it again in server side

```
app.post('/create', function (req, res)
{
   var dataReceived = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```

Comment: You were right!. I still don't know when my data should be stringified and when it shouldn't be.. anyway.. thanks!

Comment: i think if you are doing javascript on both client and server then no need of stringify !

Answer (score 2):

Set this content-type on client side ajax call if you are going to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove this content type from client request header

```
 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the KEY using the VALUE like so:

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
```