# Angularjs JSON POST data received as key instead of value in Express.js

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express

I am trying to send a POST request with JSON data from angularjs to node/express, but all the data is showing up in the **KEY** of the req.body instead of key value pairs.

I saw this question with the same issue, but the solution did not fix my problem: [Express.js : POST data as KEY of a req.body object instead of VALUE of req.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201823/express-js-post-data-as-key-of-a-req-body-object-instead-of-value-of-req-body)

Here is my client side code (ANGULARJS):

```
  var job = {
    session_id: $scope.uid,
    timestamp: 0,
    invoice_id: $params.i
  };
  var url = 'https://example/' + $scope.uid;

  var config = {
      headers : {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      }
  };

  //var config = {};
  $http.post(url, job, config).then(
  function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    console.log('Success:', response.data)
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    console.log('Error:', response.data)
  });
```

Here is my server side code (NODEJS/EXPRESS):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var domainWhitelist = ['https://www.example.com'];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(domainWhitelist.indexOf(origin) > -1){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  next();
  });
  app.post('/payment/:session', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    console.log('data:', data)
  });
```

**This is the data I get on the server side:**

```
{'{"session_id":"123","timestamp":0,"invoice_id":"-test"}': '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $http.post(url, {data:job}, config).then(
  function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    console.log('Success:', response.data)
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    console.log('Error:', response.data)
  });
```